# Set Field Disabled Based on Selected Option On Load Then On Change Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some jquery that fires when I choose another option in a select like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[name=msgType]").change(function(){
   if ($("#text").is(':selected')) { // TYPE TEXT
      $("#msgBody").removeAttr('disabled');
      $("#msgTitle").attr("disabled", "disabled");       
      $("#msgText").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      $("#msgUrl").attr("disabled", "disabled");  
      $("#msgPicUrl").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
      $("#msgVideoUrl").attr("disabled", "disabled");

   } else if ($("#link").is(':selected')) { // TYPE LINK
      $("#msgBody").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
      $("#msgTitle").removeAttr('disabled');       
      $("#msgText").removeAttr('disabled');
      $("#msgUrl").removeAttr('disabled'); 
      $("#msgPicUrl").removeAttr('disabled');
      $("#msgVideoUrl").attr("disabled", "disabled");  
   } 
 });
});
```

This works fine. However, when I initially load the page, I set the option in the select, but that obviously does not cause the "change" function to occur, so the corresponding disabled fields are not disabled until I manually change the dropdown.

How can I also set all the disabled fields for the corresponding select option when I initially load the page, but also when I change the dropdown again?

Comment: call the `.change()` manually like `$("[name=msgType]").change(function(){

 }).change();`

Comment: @guradio do this after the ready(function)? Do I have to repeat all the disabled/enabled settings for each?

Comment: @guradio I see, after the function. Yeah, that worked! Thanks.

Comment: i will put it as answer so that this question will be marked as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $("[name=msgType]").change(function(){
   if ($("#text").is(':selected')) { // TYPE TEXT
      $("#msgBody").removeAttr('disabled');
      $("#msgTitle").attr("disabled", "disabled");       
      $("#msgText").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      $("#msgUrl").attr("disabled", "disabled");  
      $("#msgPicUrl").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
      $("#msgVideoUrl").attr("disabled", "disabled");

   } else if ($("#link").is(':selected')) { // TYPE LINK
      $("#msgBody").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
      $("#msgTitle").removeAttr('disabled');       
      $("#msgText").removeAttr('disabled');
      $("#msgUrl").removeAttr('disabled'); 
      $("#msgPicUrl").removeAttr('disabled');
      $("#msgVideoUrl").attr("disabled", "disabled");  
   } 
 }).change();//call change event manually on load
```

To call the change event on load you have to manually call `.change()`